# Object creation in swift / two stage object creation in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, design-patterns, cocoa-design-patterns

I wonder how allocation and initialization works (On The Hood) in swift.

Being a beginner of swift language concepts, I wonder how the object creation works.

Does the 2 stage object creation (As in Objective C) is given a bye bye or it is hidden inside.

Comment: Why do you care? In Obj-C you always (!) used `[[Class alloc] init]`. Why shedding tears on this concept?

Comment: just curious @thomas. :/

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly, but it's a little bit tangential, if you are interested in the details of memory layouts of Swift classes and structs I recommend awesome posts by Mike Ash, for example [Exploring Swift Memory Layout, Part I](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2014-07-18-exploring-swift-memory-layout.html) and [Part II](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2014-08-01-exploring-swift-memory-layout-part-ii.html)